How to use Rasberry Pi Pico or ESP32 to print "hello world" on a TFT SPI LCD Display? Only getting white screen
I'm using a Raspberry Pi Pico (Micro RPI2040) and a ILI 9341 (I think) SPI TFT display. However, I am unable to understand how I should approach at least printing something such as "hello world".
I've tried several codes from YouTube, ChatGPT, a few google searches, etc. But none of them seem to help me. Could someone please guide me on this?
I used the ESP32 with the correct user setup configuration too but even that gives the white screen only.
I managed to get the userSetup.h file and I edited all the values to how I need it to be.
My userSetup.h file's board part -
// For ESP32 Dev board (only tested with ILI9341 display)
// The hardware SPI can be mapped to any pins

#define TFT_MISO 19
#define TFT_MOSI 21
#define TFT_SCLK 22
#define TFT_CS   15  // Chip select control pin
#define TFT_DC    2  // Data Command control pin
#define TFT_RST   4  // Reset pin (could connect to RST pin)
#define TFT_RST  -1  // Set TFT_RST to -1 if display RESET is connected to ESP32 board RST

The code I'm currently using which gives me a white screen (I'm using the clocks example from the library
/*
 An example analogue clock using a TFT LCD screen to show the time
 use of some of the drawing commands with the library.

 For a more accurate clock, it would be better to use the RTClib library.
 But this is just a demo. 
 
 This sketch uses font 4 only.

 Make sure all the display driver and pin connections are correct by
 editing the User_Setup.h file in the TFT_eSPI library folder.

 #########################################################################
 ###### DON'T FORGET TO UPDATE THE User_Setup.h FILE IN THE LIBRARY ######
 #########################################################################
 
 Based on a sketch by Gilchrist 6/2/2014 1.0
 */

#include <SPI.h>
#include <TFT_eSPI.h> // Hardware-specific library

#define TFT_GREY 0x5AEB

TFT_eSPI tft = TFT_eSPI();       // Invoke custom library

float sx = 0, sy = 1, mx = 1, my = 0, hx = -1, hy = 0;    // Saved H, M, S x & y multipliers
float sdeg=0, mdeg=0, hdeg=0;
uint16_t osx=120, osy=120, omx=120, omy=120, ohx=120, ohy=120;  // Saved H, M, S x & y coords
uint16_t x0=0, x1=0, yy0=0, yy1=0;
uint32_t targetTime = 0;                    // for next 1 second timeout

static uint8_t conv2d(const char* p); // Forward declaration needed for IDE 1.6.x
uint8_t hh=conv2d(__TIME__), mm=conv2d(__TIME__+3), ss=conv2d(__TIME__+6);  // Get H, M, S from compile time

bool initial = 1;

void setup(void) {
  tft.init();
  tft.setRotation(0);
  
  //tft.fillScreen(TFT_BLACK);
  //tft.fillScreen(TFT_RED);
  //tft.fillScreen(TFT_GREEN);
  //tft.fillScreen(TFT_BLUE);
  //tft.fillScreen(TFT_BLACK);
  tft.fillScreen(TFT_GREY);
  
  tft.setTextColor(TFT_WHITE, TFT_GREY);  // Adding a background colour erases previous text automatically
  
  // Draw clock face
  tft.fillCircle(120, 120, 118, TFT_GREEN);
  tft.fillCircle(120, 120, 110, TFT_BLACK);

  // Draw 12 lines
  for(int i = 0; i<360; i+= 30) {
    sx = cos((i-90)*0.0174532925);
    sy = sin((i-90)*0.0174532925);
    x0 = sx*114+120;
    yy0 = sy*114+120;
    x1 = sx*100+120;
    yy1 = sy*100+120;

    tft.drawLine(x0, yy0, x1, yy1, TFT_GREEN);
  }

  // Draw 60 dots
  for(int i = 0; i<360; i+= 6) {
    sx = cos((i-90)*0.0174532925);
    sy = sin((i-90)*0.0174532925);
    x0 = sx*102+120;
    yy0 = sy*102+120;
    // Draw minute markers
    tft.drawPixel(x0, yy0, TFT_WHITE);
    
    // Draw main quadrant dots
    if(i==0 || i==180) tft.fillCircle(x0, yy0, 2, TFT_WHITE);
    if(i==90 || i==270) tft.fillCircle(x0, yy0, 2, TFT_WHITE);
  }

  tft.fillCircle(120, 121, 3, TFT_WHITE);

  // Draw text at position 120,260 using fonts 4
  // Only font numbers 2,4,6,7 are valid. Font 6 only contains characters [space] 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 : . - a p m
  // Font 7 is a 7 segment font and only contains characters [space] 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 : .
  tft.drawCentreString("Time flies",120,260,4);

  targetTime = millis() + 1000; 
}

void loop() {
  if (targetTime < millis()) {
    targetTime += 1000;
    ss++;              // Advance second
    if (ss==60) {
      ss=0;
      mm++;            // Advance minute
      if(mm>59) {
        mm=0;
        hh++;          // Advance hour
        if (hh>23) {
          hh=0;
        }
      }
    }

    // Pre-compute hand degrees, x & y coords for a fast screen update
    sdeg = ss*6;                  // 0-59 -> 0-354
    mdeg = mm*6+sdeg*0.01666667;  // 0-59 -> 0-360 - includes seconds
    hdeg = hh*30+mdeg*0.0833333;  // 0-11 -> 0-360 - includes minutes and seconds
    hx = cos((hdeg-90)*0.0174532925);    
    hy = sin((hdeg-90)*0.0174532925);
    mx = cos((mdeg-90)*0.0174532925);    
    my = sin((mdeg-90)*0.0174532925);
    sx = cos((sdeg-90)*0.0174532925);    
    sy = sin((sdeg-90)*0.0174532925);

    if (ss==0 || initial) {
      initial = 0;
      // Erase hour and minute hand positions every minute
      tft.drawLine(ohx, ohy, 120, 121, TFT_BLACK);
      ohx = hx*62+121;    
      ohy = hy*62+121;
      tft.drawLine(omx, omy, 120, 121, TFT_BLACK);
      omx = mx*84+120;    
      omy = my*84+121;
    }

      // Redraw new hand positions, hour and minute hands not erased here to avoid flicker
      tft.drawLine(osx, osy, 120, 121, TFT_BLACK);
      osx = sx*90+121;    
      osy = sy*90+121;
      tft.drawLine(osx, osy, 120, 121, TFT_RED);
      tft.drawLine(ohx, ohy, 120, 121, TFT_WHITE);
      tft.drawLine(omx, omy, 120, 121, TFT_WHITE);
      tft.drawLine(osx, osy, 120, 121, TFT_RED);

    tft.fillCircle(120, 121, 3, TFT_RED);
  }
}

static uint8_t conv2d(const char* p) {
  uint8_t v = 0;
  if ('0' <= *p && *p <= '9')
    v = *p - '0';
  return 10 * v + *++p - '0';
}



This code never tries to display "hello world". It does do a lot of other unrelated stuff. Simplify it by removing all the stuff you're not trying to do and just add the code to display "hello world". A black background also would be a lot better for seeing if it works than white on gray.

@romkey yeah it's one of the examples in the library. I was asking what I would need to do if I wanted to print Hello World, because this code wasn't working. I'll use another code too but I'm pretty sure something else is the issue
